# Any way to do unqualified method calls?

Tags: ruby

If I have a script that looks like this:

```
require "FileUtils"
puts FileUtils.pwd()
```

is there anyway to do importing so that I don't have to write `FileUtils`? I want to just be able write `pwd()` instead of `FileUtils.pwd()`.

Comment: It's not `require 'FileUtils'`, it's `require 'fileutils'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'fileutils'
Object.include FileUtils
pwd
```

but never do it at home

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it and that disclaimer should be 'only do it at home' ;)

Comment: `Object.` is unnecessary, isn't it?

Comment: If you have a class / module / file that does a lot of file operations, it could be useful to `include FileUtils`. And yes, `Object.` should be avoided unless you want to include it globally.

Comment: @Stefan, sure, referring to Object explicitly will extend it globally, while implicit include will extend it locally. But in irb "locally" means in Object class, so you are extending it globally :). If you are inside another module/class local scope will be that particular module/class. Anyway being explicit is something good.

Comment: Note that this relies on the fact that the methods on `FileUtils` are all duplicated as both instance methods and singleton methods. Not all modules do this, but some (e.g. `Math`) do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you got it